# Dynamic queue implementation

Tags: c++, queue

I am new with linked lists. Every time I code I get a run time error. Same is with this also I am getting run time error in this program. Kindly explain the error in the code. I tried finding the error but every thing seems fine to me . Kindly explain.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;
node *front = NULL;
node *rear = NULL;
void enqu(int b)
{
    node *p;
    p->a = b;
    if(front == NULL)
    {
        p->next = NULL;
        front = p;
        rear = p;
    }
    else
    {
            p->next = NULL;
        rear->next = p;
        rear = p;
    }
}
void dequ()
{
    node *p;
    if (front != NULL)
    {
        if(front == rear)
        {
        front = NULL;
        rear = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            front=front->next;
        }
        cout<<"no deleated is"<<p->a<<"\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"queue is empty";
    }
}
void display()
{
    node *p;
    if(p!=NULL)
    {
        p=front;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->a;
        p=p->next;
    }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"queue is empty";
    }
}
int main()
{
    enqu(1);
    enqu(2);
    enqu(5);
    enqu(6);
    enqu(7);
    enqu(8);
    display();
    dequ();
    dequ();
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you used any debugger?

Comment: yes , its not showing any compilation error it is showing run time error

Comment: A debugger is used to at runtime not at compilation time

Comment: Hi and welcome! If you post a question like this, it really helps to state (in the question) what your expected output is, and what actually happens. So, *what* runtime error did you get? Are you using gcc, or Visual Studio, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying an un-allocated pointer is undefined behavior.

```
void enqu(int b)
{
    node *p;
    p->a = b;
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

You should use `node *p = new node;` to allocate memory, and also `delete` them somewhere.

```
void display()
{
    node *p;
    if(p!=NULL)
    {
        p=front;
        ^^^^^^^^
```

Or, set `p` to a valid allocated point. For example `node *p = front;`

You should read a lot to learn C++, read about:

- Bare pointers (`new`/`delete`)
- Smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, ...)
- STL containers (`std::list`, `std::vector`, ...)
- Try to read discussions in StackOverflow about C++

Comment: i did not get it plz explain further..what is the solution of it..?

Comment: @user2177859: Ignoring memory leaking, [here](http://ideone.com/VSbDPw) is a working code as a staring point...